# Angular directive to disable child elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it feasible to create a directive (canUpdate) which will enable me to enable/disable elements of my angular/web api application depending on results from a service that will test users permissions for a given user group or comma separated list of groups maybe.

My thinking is:

`<div><button can-update="customerMgmt">Edit customer detail</button></div>`

and my directive can perform the call to check this user is part of customerMgmt group and enable/disable appropriately.

However I am struggling to visualize/understand what my directives' template would look like.

If you was to write a directive that would perform this type of operation what would your directives' html template look like, as I'd want this to be applicable to any element, text input, button,  anchor, label etc... i'd basically be saying if the user isn't in the group(s) specified on the attribute then disable/don't allow text entry/clicking etc...

Comment: Why not use the built-in directive: ng-disabled?

Comment: I am, I want to use ng-disabled. I want to wrap the use of ng-disabled in a directive so I can simply provide a string to the directive as I show in the code snippet, and then the directive will know whether or not to switch ng-disabled or not, does this not make sense?

Comment: AFAIK, all ng-disabled is doing is to watch the value of its boolean expression, and to set/unset the disabled attribute on the element. It's quite easy to reimplement that by yourself by checking against the permissions of the current user. Check the angular source code. But you could also just expose a `hasPermission()` function in the root scope, and use `ng-disabled="!hasPermission('customerMgmt')"`. That will be much easier to combine permission checks with other echecks, like `ng-disabled="!hasPermission('customerMgmt') || form.$invalid"` for example.

Comment: So I am OK with the idea of hanging a function on the $rootScope and I'm not that fussy and anal about this sort of approach, however, some clients I have worked for are a bit purest shall we say and would poo poo this out of hand. This was why I was thinking down a directive route. I suppose what I am looking to avoid is injecting my "permissionService" into every controller then have to wrap my permissionService.canAccess method onto my controllers' viewModel. This just feels like too much work every time I write a controller that might wish to enable/disable elements

Comment: Yes, I agree. I usually don't advise putting stuff in the root scope, but in this case, since the goal is to make something globally available in all the views, it doesn't seem like such a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

So I've wrote the following that "***appears***" to be performing as I expect for now, need to test more next week but it seems to be enabling/disabling dependent on what my permissionsService.permissionsForObject method returns(which goes off to webApi controller).... Does this make sense to you?

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('blocks.permissions').directive('canWrite', canWriteDirective);

    function canWriteDirective() {
        return {
            //scope: {},
            restict: "A",
            controller: CanWriteController,
            controllerAs: "vm",
            bindToController: false,
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                controller.canWrite(iAttrs.canWrite);
            }
        }
    };

    CanWriteController.$inject = ["permissionsService"];

    function CanWriteController(permissionService) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.canWrite = canWrite;
        vm.canUpdate = false;

        function canWrite(group) {
            permissionService.permissionsForObject(group).then(function (result) {
                vm.canUpdate = true;
            }).catch(function (result) {
                vm.canUpdate = false;
            });
        }
    }

})();
```